# Where Can I Find Weapon Definitions as Refereed To In NY Penal Code?

Tags: new-york-state, self-defense, weapons, penal-law

In  NY penal code section 265.01 it states:

> A person is guilty of criminal possession of a weapon in the fourth
>   degree when:
>
> (1) He or she possesses any firearm, electronic dart gun, electronic
>   stun gun, gravity knife, switchblade knife, pilum ballistic knife,
>   metal knuckle knife, cane sword, billy, blackjack, bludgeon, plastic
>   knuckles, metal knuckles, chuka stick, sand bag, sandclub, wrist-brace
>   type slingshot or slungshot, shirken or “Kung Fu star

I found the definition of gravity knife and switchblade. Further a couple things like brass knuckles are a bit self explanatory, however, where can I find an official definition of these items?

Comment: A "metal knuckle knife" is like brass knuckles with a knife welded on one end. A lot of these can be defined by typing the name + weapon in Google, like ["blackjack weapon"](https://www.google.com/search?q=blackjack+weapon).

Answer (score 0):

[PEN § 265.00](https://codes.findlaw.com/ny/penal-law/pen-sect-265-00.html) gives all of the definitions, which includes "metal knuckle knife" but does not include yet depends on "metal knuckle". Similarly, "sand bag" is not defined. The latter omission is problematic, since many people carry sand bags in the trunk of their cars. Omission of a definition of "metal knuckles" is also a problem because we do not know if "metal knuckles" have to be made of metal (they wisely didn't specify that they have to be made of brass). In case you can't find a particular term in the definitions, you would have to search NY state case law to see if the courts have determined that any sack of sand is a weapon, or does it have to be paired with using the sack as a weapon.